# Why is my code give me , Error: Handle already running?

Tags: javascript, arrays, curl, foreach

I keep getting Error: Handle already running! It seems like the array items are not waiting for each other. how can I fix this?

```
            const curl = new(require('curl-request'))();

            sites = ["disney.com", "surfline.com", "oregon.com", "addiction.com", "www.google.com", "captaindonsfishing.com", "www.surfline.com", "facebook.com", "clevelandclinic.com"];

            sites.forEach(function(site) {

            console.log(site);

            curl.get('https://' + site)
                        .then(({statusCode}) => {

                            console.log(site+" "+statusCode);

                        }).catch((e) => {
                            console.log(site+" "+e);
                });

            });
```

**Output:**

surfline.com Error: Handle already running!

oregon.com Error: Handle already running!

addiction.com Error: Handle already running!

www.google.com Error: Handle already running!

captaindonsfishing.com Error: Handle already running!

www.surfline.com Error: Handle already running!

facebook.com Error: Handle already running!

clevelandclinic.com Error: Handle already running!

disney.com [object Arguments]

Comment: does this lib supports multiple requests?

Comment: `const curl = new(require('curl-request'))();` seems like a bad idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can send a second request with the same `curl` object until the first one completes. If you want to send multiple concurrent requests, you need to create multiple objects.

```
const CurlRequest = require('curl-request');
sites.forEach(site => {
    console.log(site);
    const curl = new CurlRequest;
    curl.get('https://' + site).then(...);
});
```